# How to concatenate variable with string

Tags: powershell

I just started using powershell and i want to write basic shell script to delete Windows 10 defaults apps,, like XBOX,Instagram and others, this is how my script looks like.

```
$appXPackage = "Get-AppXPackage -Name"
$appXPackage + ' Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI' | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Getting this Error:

```
Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFA, Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor. (
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFA)
Package Manager aborted the Remove operation because an invalid argument was passed: Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Xb
oxGameCallableUI.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] eb445625-b0a9-0002-d590-44eba9b0d301 in the Event Log or use th
e command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID eb445625-b0a9-0002-d590-44eba9b0d301
At C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\Remove Windows 10 Apps.ps1:11 char:50
+ $appXPackage + ' Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI' | Remove-AppxPackage
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Get-AppXPackage...xGameCallableUI:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

**EDIT:**
And how can i story applications names inside array and loop through it

Comment: Why are you attempting to store `Get-AppXPackage -Name` in a string? Why not just call the cmdlet directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the intermediate step of attempting to store half a statement in a string:

```
$PackageName = 'Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI' 
Get-AppxPackage -Name $PackageName | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: Thanks any way i can store all apps name inside array and loop throughout it?

Comment: to simply remove everything that is in Get-AppXPackage try this:

    `Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage` 

I would run this first to make sure you truly want to remove all of that
    
`Get-AppXPackage | Select Name`

Comment: @Andrew of course there is, please update your question to show what you're actually trying to do, don't make us guess or write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

This way you could define the application packages you want to remove.

```
$applicationPackages = "Application.Name","Application2.Name","Application3.Name"
Foreach($application in $applicationPackages){
    Remove-AppxPackage -Name $application
}
```

One step further if you know part of the names you could do this to create the array

```
$applicationPackages = Get-AppxPackage | where-object {$_.Name -match "someapplication*|someotherApplication*"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to create a Windows 10 image. You're running sysprep, and you're bumping into that issue with the default programs? ...Microsoft.

This is what you're asking about.

```
$list_of_packages = @('Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI', '...', '...')

foreach ($package_name in $list_of_packages) {
  Remove-AppXPackage -Name $package_name
}
```

But, let's skip ahead. You'll probably try the following if you haven't already...

- [remove-default-apps.ps1](https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10/blob/master/scripts/remove-default-apps.ps1)
- [How to Remove All Built-in Apps in Windows 10](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-remove-all-built-in-apps-in-windows-10/)

Good luck.